# Combinatorics with double factorial

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinations

> Let $\{1,\dots, 2n\}$ and a table with $n$ columns and two rows. Suppose we want to arrange each number uniquely on the table (each number only appears once) such that the number in the upper row is greater than the one in the same column at the lower row. In how many different ways can this be done?

I said, consider the number $2n$, it has exactly $2n-1$ numbers which it is greater of. Suppose we choose one out of them. Now fix $m \in \{1,\dots,2n\}$ as the biggest value which is still unpaired. So, $m$ is not equal to $2n$ and so it cant be that one it was paired to. Hence there are $2n-3$ options for $m$. Continuing in this way, it ends up we have:

$$ (2n-1) \cdot (2n-3)\cdot\cdots  \cdot 3 \cdot 1 = (2n-1)!! $$

desired pairs. From here, we want to arrange them within the table which is achieved by multiplication of $(2n-1)!!$ by $n!$.

Since this solution describes really distinct problems I've encountered with, my intuition feels like this answer is incorrect or my arguments above are missing something. Could someone let me know what he/she thinks?

Comment: $(2n-1)!!*n!$ is correct, and seems a simpler solution. $(2n-1)!!$ counts all possible pairings (each can be arranged in only one possible way in a column), and $n!$ permutes them in the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Filling Procedure**

We fill the slots column by column. Choose $2$ numbers, put the larger of the two in the first row and the smaller number below it. Repeat this $n$ times until you have filled all columns and rows. Total number of possibilities:

$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-2i}{2} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}}
$$

Comment: And what about arranging the pairs at the table itself?

Comment: @X4J in the procedure I mentioned, we fill the first column first, then the second, and so on until the last column. So the arrangement of the pairs has been counted in the formula as well.

Comment: oh, it does count any internal combination too. So if you didnt want to count the internal combinations, denote the combinations number we want to find by A, then each combination at A has n! internal combinations and we have A * n! = (2n)! / 2^n, which is A = (2n)!/ (2^n * n). Is that correct?

Comment: @X4J if you mean $\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot 2^{n}}$ then yes it is correct

Comment: @X4J See also https://oeis.org/A000680 for other combinatorial settings leading to these numbers.